# How to display progress bar for tar incremental archives?

Tags: tar

While creating a level-0 archive I can do this:

```
 tar -cf - . | pv -s $(du -sb . | awk '{print $1}') | gzip > out.tgz
```

But in case of a level-1 (incremental) archive, I don't know beforehand what the size of data to be archived will be.
So I can't give that value to `pv` with the `-s` parameter (or have any idea about how long it'll take).

What can be done?

Comment: `tar -c --checkpoint=.[FREQ_NUM]` where the `$FREQ_NUM` refers to a count of *records* processed - which are 10240 bytes each by default. You don't need `pv` or `awk` for this with GNU `tar`.

Comment: @mikeserv that's good to know. but I still like the pv's display better. And this way it's still not possible to know when the operation is going to end.

Comment: There are many kinds of `--checkpoint-action` from among which I mentioned only the most trivial. You can run a script, for example. You can find more in `info tar`.

Comment: [this](http://www.thedoghousediaries.com/dhdcomics/2011-02-25-ce0bae6.png)

Comment: First, you are not talking about `tar` but about `gtar`. Second: be careful, GNU tar supports incremental backups but fails to restore them in case of special constraints with renamed directories. If you like to use a verified incremental backup method, I recommend `star`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you perform your incremental archives by `tar`ring the directory and running the output through a filter that returns the difference between this and your existing archives, your current progress calculation could be fine in this case. Why? Because progress is determined by how much of the directory has `tar` read so far.

Now then, this is just a supposition. Care to share the command you use to make an incremental archive?